# combine OR and And Condtion without repeating in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select phone number that is between date_from and date_to 
or the date_to is null
but the problem in the Or part it neglects the other conditions  (where pho.parent_id =:p_id and pho.phone_type='M' and rownum <=1 )

```
  select pho.PHONE_NUMBER 
    from per_phones pho 
    where pho.parent_id = :p_id and 
    pho.phone_type='M' 
    and 
    rownum <=1 and sysdate > pho.DATE_FROM and sysdate < DATE_TO or DATE_TO is null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `OR condition` within braces

```
select pho.PHONE_NUMBER 
    from per_phones pho 
    where pho.parent_id = :p_id and pho.phone_type='M' 
    and rownum <=1 and 
      (sysdate > pho.DATE_FROM and sysdate < DATE_TO or DATE_TO is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `DATE_TO` is null in case your record is valid from `DATE_FROM` till end of time.

You will still need to check `DATE_FROM` condition and also put `rownum` condition in the outer query so you need following:

```
Select PHONE_NUMBER from
(select pho.PHONE_NUMBER 
  from per_phones pho 
 where pho.parent_id = :p_id 
   and pho.phone_type='M' 
   and rownum <= 1 -- this is not needed here
   and sysdate > pho.DATE_FROM 
   and (sysdate < DATE_TO or DATE_TO is null)
)
 Where rownum <= 1
```

Cheers!!